# How to cut the string in cookie for some alphabet

Tags: java, javascript, php, cookies

i made a cookie for some value like this

```
setCookie("1", 'A'.fontcolor('green'), 365);
```

And, of course it worked!! it shown A in green.

if i want this cookie(Name="1") to show A,which don't have anycolor,How could i do that ???

I've tried for many times to use "`.split`" but the result is still green A.
Plz help me ...

Answer (score 0):

When you get the value of cookie part that in substrings based upon dot (.) and show first part. For it you can use JavaScript function substr(a,b) and indexOf(a,b).

For Example:

```
var i = 'A'.fontcolor('green'); // cookie value

i = i.substr(0,i.indexOf('.',0)-1);

alert(i);
```

Comment: it's not worked T.T i just tried but i don't know why it's not show anything up .